# Primitive radical extension with $n$-th root with Galois group smaller than $n$

Tags: galois-theory, radicals

It is a well-known theorem in Field Theory that if $F$ is a field:

1. Which contains the $n$-th roots of unity for some $n\ge 1$.
2. Is of characteristic not dividing $n$.

   And if $0\ne a\in F$ is some element, then the primitive radical extension $F(\sqrt[n]{a})/F$ is a Galois extension with $\textbf{Gal}(F(\sqrt[n]{a})/F)\cong \mathbb{Z}_d$ such that $d|n$.

I am looking for examples (preferably over characteristic 0, is such examples exist) for such extensions where $d<n$.

Comment: Sure: $a=4$, $n=2$, where $\Bbb Q(\sqrt4\,)=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I actually thought about this case and now I'm not sure why I decided it's not a satisfying counterexample.

Comment: Probably because $\Bbb Q$ doesn’t contain the *fourth* roots of unity. I should have taken the base field to be the Gaussian numbers, $\Bbb Q(i)$. Otherwise, same example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be the extension of the rationals got by joining a primitive 15th root of unity. Take $a=8$. Then the extension $F[ 8^{1/15}]$ of $F$ will have Galois group cyclic of order 5. (Because 8 already has cubic roots in $F$).

Comment: So basically I can only expect $d < n$ when $a$ is already a $n/d$-power of an element of F?

Comment: Yes. Because in this  examole qe srw adjoining actually the fifth root of 5. This is already implicit in the  comment by Lubin.