# On the irreducibility over cyclotomic field in radical extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, cyclotomic-fields

I'm interested in the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[20]{2},\zeta_{20})$ of polynomial $f(x):=x^{20}-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta_{20}=e^{\tfrac{2\pi i}{20}}$.

Clearly, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein at $p=2$.

But, I'm not sure whether $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ or not.

In order to show the irreduciblity of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$, is it enough to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})=\mathbb{Q}$?

The reason I thought it was enough to see that is:

> Because there are only three quadratic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}),\mathbb{Q}(i),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}i)$, and every nontrivial intermediate field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.
>
> Thus, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})=\mathbb{Q}$.

I would be grateful if someone could confirm that my claim is correct or incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ and $L=\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{20},\sqrt[20]{2})$. We wish to compute $[L:\mathbf{Q}]$.

The intermediate field $K$ has degree $\phi(20)=\phi(5)\phi(4)=4\cdot 2=8$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.

The extension $L/K$ is a so called radical extension since $K$ already contains a primitive $20$th root of unity. From this [theorem in field theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841203/primitive-radical-extension-with-n-th-root-with-galois-group-smaller-than-n), it is a cyclic extension of degree equal to $20/d$, where $d$ is the greatest divisor of $20$ for which $x^d=2$ for some $x\in K$.

We ask ourselves since $20=2^2\cdot 5$, is $\sqrt[10]{2}\in K$? Is $\sqrt[5]{2}\in K?$ Is $\sqrt[4]{2}\in K$? Is $\sqrt{2}\in K$?

Now clearly $\sqrt[10]{2},\sqrt[5]{2}\not\in K$, since those have degree $10$ and $5$ over $\mathbf{Q}$; $10>8$ and $5$ is coprime to $8$..

Furthermore, $\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt{2}\not\in K$, since as you noticed, $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not an intermediate field of $K/\mathbf{Q}$.

Hence $L/K$ is a (cyclic) extension of degree $20$ and we conclude $\boxed{[L:\mathbf{Q}]=8\cdot 20=160}$.

To answer your question: $f$ is *indeed* irreducible over $K[X]$, but it requires some more work.. :)

Comment: Then, if we put the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\sqrt[20]{2}$ over $K$ as $p(x):=\text{irr}(\alpha,K)$, we have $p(x)\mid f(x)$. Furthermore, we already know that both $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ have same degree and monic. Thus, $f(x)$ equals $p(x)$, and hence, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$. - Is this the remaining some more work you mentioned?

Comment: What is you say is correct! But I meant that it requires more work to show that $f$ is irreducible than just proving $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{20})=\mathbf{Q}$ as you claimed in your question ;)

Comment: Thank you for making sure. I thought that it is enough to consider only prime divisors of $20$ for showing $\sqrt[d]{2}\not\in K$ whenever $d\mid 20$ since $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.