# Quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ inside cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

[Primavera](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615141/477927) stated a question, and mentioned that...

> There are only three quadratic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}),\mathbb{Q}(i),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}i)$, and every nontrivial intermediate field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.

I assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ is the field generated by all roots,
which orders are exactly 20.

Why is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ lies inside $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$?

Which minimal polynomial does $\sqrt{5}$ have, $x^2 - 5$ doesn't appear to lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{4},\zeta_{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$, where $\zeta_{k}$ is $k$th primitive root of unity.

Comment: @Primavera, thanks for your attention, since you are here, how can I see that there are exactly $3$ quadratic fields inside? Is it because there are two generators $\zeta_4, \zeta_5$?

Comment: Because, there are only three subgroups of index $2$ in $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\zeta_{20}$ is the first $20$th root of unity, so it follows that $\zeta_{20}^4=\zeta_5$, the first fifth root of unity. Now
$$\zeta_5+\zeta_5^4=2\cos\frac{2\pi}5=\frac{\sqrt5-1}2$$
so this shows $\sqrt5$, and hence $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$, lies in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{20})$.

Comment: So, to be more concrete, $$(2(\zeta_{20}+\zeta_{20}^4)+1)^2=5$$